# self.navigationItem.title issue iOS7

Tags: ios7, uinavigationitem

I just can`t put any title on navigationItem.

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"My Account";
```

I don`t see any deprecation warning, anyone knows something about it?

THanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                     [UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                                     [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                                     [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"My Account";
```

You need to set TextAttributes or won't work.

Comment: This worked for me but it seems sort of silly we have to do it. Any idea why this is now needed?

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer to replace deprecated properties.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar 
    setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
    [UIColor whiteColor], NSShadowAttributeName,
    [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

do

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.title = @"My Account";
```

Comment: what is navigationItem? is it something you created or are you doing it with navigation controller?

Comment: Navigation controller, in iOS6 and before self.navigationItem.title = @"My Account"; works well